# Removed transaction

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, mycelium-wallet, bitfinex

I have [*this transaction*](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/172bbca8d4bad4401e9d732daf01c8c2e13319032cbb03573455e49d3a271e5e) I made some days ago (8) and it wasn't processed by the miners and it was unconfirmed (for very low fee). Today I made a quick check and it looks like **REMOVED / EXPIRED**. What should I do? It will be send back to my wallet?

For info: it's a transaction from Mycelium (Android wallet) to Bitfinex.
Thanks everyone!

[**TRANSACTION LINK**](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/172bbca8d4bad4401e9d732daf01c8c2e13319032cbb03573455e49d3a271e5e)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, send another transaction with a significantly higher fee. You should look at [this chart](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactionfees.html) to estimate how much fees you should be paying.

Comment: Since I have no money on my wallet I can be little tricky. Is there another way?

Comment: What wallet are you using?

Comment: I wrote it, `Mycelium`. The thing is that I transfered ALL the `BTC` I had on that wallet to my Bitfinex account, so send another transaction can be painful becuase I have to buy BTC, then send to `Mycelium` wallet and the send to `Bitfinex` = A LOT OF FEE. I'm wondering if is exist another way

Comment: Don't buy more BTC, you do not need to. You should have an option for CPFP (Child pays for parent) on Mycelium. That's what you should be looking for. I did a little search and looks like Mycelium has a "Bump fee" feature which is what you should do.

Comment: Yeah, I found it but it gives me error, probably because it need more BTC to use as fee and my wallet is completely 0.

Comment: You can't do a CPFP here, the recipient is an exchange wallet. You got 3 options: [1. Ask miners for help 2. Double-spend aka replace-by-fee 3. Wait until it gets dropped by mempool or confirmed by its own](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Answer (score 0):

This happened because the network was full and you tx had to low fee, so that it got pruned from the blockchain mempool database after a while.

But as you can see there https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/911e63f1e674bc5ca50f39a3003e5a08307e04bfbdb3aa50f59fe3bc4f56a2b3 the previous tx which remained unconfirmed has been spent again from the same input but , this time, with an adequate fee to let miners process it in a reasonable time.

If you check first transaction link https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/172bbca8d4bad4401e9d732daf01c8c2e13319032cbb03573455e49d3a271e5e you can notice the label "Double Spend" in the "Confirmations" field and just below which is the TX where this input has been "double spended".

Pay attention this is a "pseudo double spend" cause effectively no coins are spent two times.